# Is it possible to convert a 3D Max file into maxscript?

Tags: maxscript

I want to convert a 3D scene into a script that can generate that scene, is there a way to convert a scene into a Maxscript script that when run will recreate that scene?
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the old BFF (Back From Five/Bobo's File Format) which did that back in the day but it wasn't maintained and doesn't have full coverage for animation, modifier data or classes but it might be a good starting point for you:

http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/bff-bobos-file-format